# Child theme is showing blank page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I have created a child theme. After activation, it is showing a blank page. How do I solve it? Please check the following code and let me know, what is the mistake. 
style.css-

[image]

functions.php-

[image]

As you can see the theme is activated-

[image]

Showing a blank page on the browser-

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the closing ?>    sometimes that does it

Comment: as per here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289695/child-theme-showing-a-blank-page-when-activated-and-causing-log-in-problems

Comment: @anmari I have tried it, but still it is not working.

Comment: Try this http://nerodev.com/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you do not have new line character in your action name so it reads like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing 'parent-style' in the enqueue function, write 'twentyfifteen-style'. The word 'parent' is just a placeholder as an example.